Should set of product attribute considered a column stored as array?
Supposedly I got a products table:



Id
product_name




1
Jeans Shirt


2
Pie



Except the variant of product with options like:



id
product_id
name




1
1
Color


2
2
Flavor



So, I want to storing a set of attribute

Jeans Shirt : manufacturing date, material, pattern design, style, origin, seasons (autumn,summer,spring,winter)

Pie : Recommended age, Ingredients, Food type, Flavor, Production date, Expiry date )


With all of this I came up like:

I store a set a attributes as a columns and it would be an array:




Id
product_name
attr_set




1
Jeans Shirt
[manufacturing date, material, ....]


2
Pie
[Recommended age, Ingredients, Food ty, .... ]




I split into a separately a table a linked into a table product with 1-N relations :




Id
product_id
attr_name




1
1
manufacturing date


2
1
material


..
...
....


11
2
Recommended age


12
2
Ingredients



All set attribute I intended to bring is the default which meant all attribute is based on product , admin cant CRUD its ?
So I wonder What case would be reasonable when designing the database in e-commerce ?
https://i.ibb.co/5WyMnPV/Screenshot-2024-04-05-190859.png
My database

You will need to think about how you are intending to store the values. If those arrays in solution 1 are actually textual values (varchars or the like), then think again. You will likely need statistics and ease for searching the individual items, so you will need to comply to 1NF and avoid having fields that contain multiple elements.
Of course, some RDBMS systems allow the type of array, which is an alternative (example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), but you can easily get into trouble with the number of elements or the need to elaborate on those elements if they turn out to be more than just the value you are storing in the array and you will have lots of troubles with values semantically identical, but technically different, such as manufacturing date vs manufactured date. So it makes sense to have predefined possible values for attributes in a separate table and all uses of values would be done through their id, so you will have the attribute names stored in a single place and changing those values would be trivial, without dangers of inconsistency due to redundancy. You will also have difficulty migrating array values between different flavors of RDBMSs or to use arrays in older versions of the same RDBMS if you end up needing it.
So, for theoretical and practical reasons you might choose the following setup:
attributes



Id
name




1
manufacturing date


2
material



and
product_attributes



Id
product_id
attr_id




1
1
1


2
1
2


..
...
....


11
2
3


12
1
4




I'm not sure what the down-vote was given for, but I have improved the format of the tables in the answer if that was the reason.

Thank you for that, though I cannot undo the downvote but you answer give me something I can do for now

Anyway, I think your solution is reasonable, somehow I asked in laracasts they said my DB should not have the table attribute_products because IF the variant table already linked with the attribute(options) which meant those helped for each product when mixed by SKUs each other , and the product table is ONLY the parent table and this table shouldn't have attributes table linked with. So my database is upload there which you can see

@user01521879 Since you already have a product_attribute_values table, you might not need a product_attributes table, unless an attribute might have multiple values.

Actually attribute can have multiple values as you said , I meant if Jeans have attr: the manufacturing country of country A and country B, so there would be more than 1 value

@user01521879 then it makes sense to have both tables.
